# JQuery Substr start at letter

Tags: jquery, substr, letter

Is it possible for a substr to start at a letter with jQuery?

The following does not work:

```
var naam = cid.substr('|');
```

The | is there I want it to start.

It works now, one of the solutions is:

```
var naampos = cid.indexOf('|');
var naam = cid.substr(naampos+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `indexOf` to get the first occurrence of the character you want to start at, then use the index of the character in the `substr` function.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubWm9/1/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want substring you can use

```
naam.substring(0,5);
```

you can split the word and get the second element..

```
naam.split('|');
alert(naam[1]);
```

Here is it :http://jsfiddle.net/anish/JBrLx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look :

http://jsfiddle.net/Kris_I/y7vjj/

```
var myVar = "I do @Test";

var pos = myVar.indexOf('@');

alert(myVar.substring(pos + 1, 400));
```